# fckeditor plugin to insert html

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, fckeditor

I have an issue with inserting an HTML into WYSYWIG with my custome plugin
All links across the internet I've ever seen for this theme says you should use

```
FCK.InsertHtml();
```

But using this I have faced the following problem:
HTML content befort InsertHtml():

```
<div>
<em>
<strong>
<font size="5">
<font face="Georgia">

123

</font>
</font>
</strong>
</em>
</div>
```

then I select the character '2' and insert an html using FCK.InsertHtml(); and get the following:

```
<div>
<em>
<strong>
<font size="5">
<font face="Georgia">

1

</font>
</font>
</strong>
</em>

<a class="subscribeNow" href="#ORDER_FORM_LINK#">2</a>

<em>
<strong>
<font size="5">
<font face="Georgia">

3

</font>
</font>
</strong>
</em>
</div>
```

As you can see the WYSYWIG autocloses some tags and as a result the mockup is broken.
Has anyone an idea how to insert html without these additional source manipulation?

Comment: fckeditor was changed to ckeditor quite a while ago - for the best security, I would recommend you use the new version

Comment: can you confirm that this feature works the other way in ckeditor rather than in fckeditor? A lot of plugins were made for our version of editor and this is not an option to just update it

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to answer that - all I know is we had a site that was running fckeditor (I can't remember which version) which contained a security flaw allowing access to our server. I understand your upgrade issues, and yes I would suggest there is a high posibility that your custom plugins would *not* work on the new ckeditor.  Sorry, and good luck

Answer (score 0):

First of all - FCKEditor is predecessor of CKEditor and its support was dropped few years ago. My answer will be valid for CKEditor, but I'm not sure if for FCKeditor as well.

`editor#insertHtml` is a method which is heavily used when user pastes content - this is its main function. In current CKEditor version this method works based on the native HTML insertion algorithm implemented in browsers. So in fact we, developers of CKEditor, haven't got much to say about those algorithms - we can't change them. However, except for many differences between browsers, which we don't like very much, we accept these algorithms, because their behaviour is more or less correct.

Why is it correct? Let's say you've got bolded text in MSWord. You copied it and you're pasting it in text that's underlined. What happens? Text that you've pasted isn't underlined, it's only bolded. That's because MSWord assumes that you want to keep styles of copied content. And CKEditor is indented to work exactly the same.

The solution for you will be to use `editor#insertElement` method which will insert your data (one element) without these special operations. If you want to insert more elements at once then you'll have to do this in loop.

This is example usage of `insertElement` (you can test it e.g. on http://ckeditor.com/demo after setting content of editor to `<p><strong>te^xt</strong></p>` and placing caret in place of `^`):

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1,
    element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<u>xxx</u>' );

editor.insertElement( element ); // result: <p><strong>te<u>xxx</u>xt</strong></p>
editor.insertHtml( '<i>yyy</i>' ); // result: <p><strong>te<u>xxx</u></strong><i>yyy</i><strong>xt</strong></p>
```

Results may be different if you'll test on other than Chrome browser.

PS. In the new CKEditor version inserting content without preserving styles will be simplified, because we're aware of this problem.